# AWS ECS task stuck in PROVISIONING state

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs

My ECS cluster has 2 t3.xlarge instances and I created a service with 2 tasks, but the tasks remain in PROVISIONING state. Container is running on port 5020 and it is mapped to host port 5040. There are other services running on the same cluster with port mapping 5020:5020 and its working fine.

Should I make any changes to move the task to PENDING/RUNNING state?

Comment: Are you sure one of your t3.xlarge servers has enough RAM and CPU unreserved that it can support the new service you are trying to deploy?

Comment: Yes, It has enough memory and cpu to accommodate the new task. I think if cpu or memory is not available on the instance, task remains in PENDING state which comes after PROVISIONING in task lifecycle. Does ECS check any other parameters before moving the task to PENDING state?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I can share one problem and solution scenario, which is not commonly described and you cannot easily find answer, as there is no error message.

The ECS Service is in ACTIVE status, but it's Task is stuck in `Last status PROVISIONING` and `Desired status RUNNING` and
`Health Status UNKNOWN` and zero logs in CloudWatch, thus you have not option to look by Error message.

It appears, that Developers have not pushed Docker Container Image to corresponding AWS ECR! That was it!

ECR repository is empty, does not contain any image to send, thus AWS ECS (Fargate) Service is stuck in PROVISIONING state, as it is waiting for available container image to download.